# Android - MediaRecorder crashes when stop is called very soon after start

Tags: android, mediarecorder

The core of the problem is in the following. I have a MediaRecorder object called recorder. If I have code that allows recorder.stop() to execute very soon after recorder.start() then my android app crashes. Indeed, if I write something like:

```
recorder.start();
sleep(T);
recorder.stop();
```

(in pseudocode, e.g. put the sleep in a runnable), then it takes around T >~ 80ms for the app to stop crashing.

1. Why is this happening? I don't really know the details of how MediaRecorder works.
2. And what do you think is the best way to prevent this from happening? One obvious way is to add a very slight delay to the stopRecording routine which would not be particularly noticeable. Another is to put the stop in a try { } statement. But why doesn't the documentation do that in its example? Am I missing something simple?

It would be nice to not record such short recordings, since they would probably be made by mistake anyway.

---

Ps: the problem in context:

I am experimenting with a very simple MediaRecorder application, based on [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#sample-code) example in the documentation, which works fine under normal circumstances. However, if the user toggles the record button on and off very rapidly, the app will crash. The diagnostics shows that it crashes on the recorder.stop() method. With some more diagnostics, I can see that it crashes when recorder is not null, and in fact after the recorder has gone through the prepare and start stage. This is confirmed by doing an experiment with the above code.

This is particularly relevant if I want to record whilst a button is depressed, which is a convenient way of encouraging short recordings. Then the possibility of taps means that the crashing behavior above is unacceptable.

Comment: What does the stack-trace show?